# Increment date/day in PL/SQL without + sign

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

Is there a way to increment day without + sign?

Instead of

```
to_date('06/07/2012 08:00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')+1
```

Something that will make it increment a day or more.

Comment: Would u explain why the strange demand? Is it an XY problem?

Comment: I'm trying to pass above line as a url parameter, Using jsp. But Url doesn't like + sign =/

Comment: Sayhaha, I think allowing the above line to added as a URL parameter would present a security risk which could leave your application open to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: As said, it is a sql injection risk, but, I am sure JSP has some kind of a urlencode /urldecode function to handle such signs, as any other modern language

Comment: @Rob Kielty This is for the internal use so it should be okay...? But thanks for heads up. Another thing to study!

Comment: @sayhaha It's never ending for sure:) The Open Web Application Secuirty Project OWASP is a good source for such info https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page and more specifically https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: Itay is right the thing to do here would be to keep the Oracle syntax for adding a day and URLEncode the parameter in query string.  see https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=740265&tstart=60

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the Oracle PL/SQL syntax for adding a day to a date and use [URLEncode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) to encode string which will encode the plus sign in the parameter in query string.

See also https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=740265&tstart=60

However we have to sound a note of caution that there is risk of an SQL Injection attack here which is best avoided even if it is an internal web app.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has already been answered, however the best practice for avoiding SQL injection is to use bind variables.  So if you had a pl/sql procedure let's say (note: bind variables can be used in almost every language Java, C, C#), here is how you'd use bind variables to completely avoid SQL injection.

```
create or replace function increment_day(date_string_in varchar2)
return date
is

begin
   return to_date(date_string_in,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')+1;


end;
```